# Getting inside JSON directory?

Tags: json, swift

JSON:

```
{"status":"ok","count":4,"count_total":4,"pages":1,"posts":[{"id":15,"type":"post","slug":"sg-and-t13-friends-again","url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/sg-and-t13-friends-again\/","status":"publish","title":"SG and T13 friends again","title_plain":"SG and T13 friends again","content":"<p>again?<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>again?<\/p>\n","date":"2014-10-08 20:28:52","modified":"2014-10-08 20:28:52","categories":[{"id":2,"slug":"selena-gomez","title":"Selena Gomez","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":3},{"id":3,"slug":"taylor-swift","title":"Taylor Swift","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":2}],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[{"id":16,"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","slug":"tumblr_nc5rkwqj1r1tv3z6lo1_500","title":"tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500","description":"","caption":"","parent":15,"mime_type":"image\/png","images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-150x150.png","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-238x300.png","width":238,"height":300},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-360x200.png","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-360x360.png","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-500x420.png","width":500,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630}}}],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","thumbnail":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-150x150.png","custom_fields":{"vw_review_average_score":["0"],"vw_post_featured":["0"],"vw_post_layout":["right"],"vw_enable_review":["0"]},"thumbnail_size":"thumbnail","thumbnail_images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-150x150.png","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-238x300.png","width":238,"height":300},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-360x200.png","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-360x360.png","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500-500x420.png","width":500,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_nc5rkwQj1R1tv3z6lo1_500.png","width":500,"height":630}}},{"id":9,"type":"post","slug":"selena-gomez-new-trailer","url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/selena-gomez-new-trailer\/","status":"publish","title":"Selena Gomez new trailer","title_plain":"Selena Gomez new trailer","content":"<p>Not really\u00a0&#8220;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&#8221;<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>Not really\u00a0&#8220;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, &#8230;<\/p>\n","date":"2014-10-08 20:22:02","modified":"2014-10-08 20:25:19","categories":[{"id":2,"slug":"selena-gomez","title":"Selena Gomez","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":3}],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[{"id":11,"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842.jpg","slug":"img_1842","title":"IMG_1842","description":"","caption":"","parent":9,"mime_type":"image\/jpeg","images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842.jpg","width":1280,"height":1024},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-300x240.jpg","width":300,"height":240},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-1024x819.jpg","width":1024,"height":819},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-360x200.jpg","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-360x360.jpg","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-750x420.jpg","width":750,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-750x750.jpg","width":750,"height":750},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-1140x641.jpg","width":1140,"height":641}}}],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","thumbnail":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-150x150.jpg","custom_fields":{"vw_review_average_score":["0"],"vw_post_featured":["0"],"vw_post_layout":["right"],"vw_enable_review":["0"]},"thumbnail_size":"thumbnail","thumbnail_images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842.jpg","width":1280,"height":1024},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-300x240.jpg","width":300,"height":240},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-1024x819.jpg","width":1024,"height":819},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-360x200.jpg","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-360x360.jpg","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-750x420.jpg","width":750,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-750x750.jpg","width":750,"height":750},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/IMG_1842-1140x641.jpg","width":1140,"height":641}}},{"id":7,"type":"post","slug":"taylor-swift-new-album","url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/taylor-swift-new-album\/","status":"publish","title":"Taylor Swift new album","title_plain":"Taylor Swift new album","content":"<p>3 weeks!\u00a0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<\/p>\n<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>3 weeks!\u00a0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, &#8230;<\/p>\n","date":"2014-10-08 20:21:20","modified":"2014-10-08 20:27:44","categories":[{"id":3,"slug":"taylor-swift","title":"Taylor Swift","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":2}],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[{"id":14,"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","slug":"tumblr_ncqmsrndkv1rx2xpto1_500","title":"tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500","description":"","caption":"","parent":7,"mime_type":"image\/jpeg","images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","width":500,"height":648},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-231x300.jpg","width":231,"height":300},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","width":500,"height":648},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-360x200.jpg","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-360x360.jpg","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-500x420.jpg","width":500,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","width":500,"height":648},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-500x641.jpg","width":500,"height":641}}}],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","thumbnail":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-150x150.jpg","custom_fields":{"vw_review_average_score":["0"],"vw_post_featured":["0"],"vw_post_layout":["right"],"vw_enable_review":["0"]},"thumbnail_size":"thumbnail","thumbnail_images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","width":500,"height":648},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-231x300.jpg","width":231,"height":300},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","width":500,"height":648},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-360x200.jpg","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-360x360.jpg","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-500x420.jpg","width":500,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500.jpg","width":500,"height":648},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/tumblr_ncqmsrndkV1rx2xpto1_500-500x641.jpg","width":500,"height":641}}},{"id":5,"type":"post","slug":"selena-gomez-reported-pregnant","url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/selena-gomez-reported-pregnant\/","status":"publish","title":"Selena Gomez reported pregnant","title_plain":"Selena Gomez reported pregnant","content":"<p>yolo? fake!<\/p>\n","excerpt":"<p>yolo? fake!<\/p>\n","date":"2014-10-08 20:20:17","modified":"2014-10-08 20:26:23","categories":[{"id":2,"slug":"selena-gomez","title":"Selena Gomez","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":3}],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"slug":"admin","name":"admin","first_name":"","last_name":"","nickname":"admin","url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[{"id":12,"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","slug":"selena-gomez-photoshoot","title":"Selena Gomez - Photoshoot","description":"","caption":"","parent":5,"mime_type":"image\/jpeg","images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-300x225.jpg","width":300,"height":225},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-360x200.jpg","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-360x360.jpg","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-720x420.jpg","width":720,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541}}}],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"open","thumbnail":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-150x150.jpg","custom_fields":{"vw_review_average_score":["0"],"vw_post_featured":["0"],"vw_post_layout":["right"],"vw_enable_review":["0"]},"thumbnail_size":"thumbnail","thumbnail_images":{"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541},"thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-150x150.jpg","width":150,"height":150},"medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-300x225.jpg","width":300,"height":225},"large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541},"vw_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-360x200.jpg","width":360,"height":200},"vw_square_small":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-360x360.jpg","width":360,"height":360},"vw_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot-720x420.jpg","width":720,"height":420},"vw_square_medium":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541},"vw_large":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com.com\/instanews\/wp-content\/uploads\/Selena-Gomez-Photoshoot.jpg","width":720,"height":541}}}],"query":{"ignore_sticky_posts":true}}
```

I'm trying to get the full picture from the first post. My solution (which works):

```
let urlPath = "http://example.com/instanews/api/get_posts/"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if((error) != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            var result: AnyObject = jsonResult["posts"]! as NSArray
            var result2: AnyObject = result[0]!
            var result3: AnyObject = result2["attachments"]!!
            var result4: AnyObject = result3[0]!
            var result5: AnyObject = result4["images"]!!
            var result6: AnyObject = result5["full"]!!
            var result7: AnyObject = result6["url"]!!
            println(result7)

        }

    })
    task.resume()
```

I'm not happy with those var result7 etc. this is obviously not the right way to do it. I'm not quite sure why can't we just use result["posts"][0] and stack it like that.

Also can you please explain why sometimes there has to be double exclamation point? I know that it is force unwrap, but why is it double?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use some native swift json library that can take advantage of the Optional semantic  e.g. https://github.com/owensd/json-swift

Then your code could be rewritten as

```
if let result7 = jsonResult["posts"]["attachments"]["images"]["full"]["url"].string {
    println(result7)
}
```

Comment: tried this but error occured: AnyObject? does not have a member "subscript"

Comment: What json library are you using now?